# Splashscreen not displayed on Phonegap 3.3

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

The splashscreen is not displayed in my application, this is the part about splashscreen in my config.xml, located in the root directory:

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>

<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>

<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

<gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />

<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
```

This is the plugin correctly installed:

```
smartbox:yo du$ phonegap local plugin list | grep splash  
[phonegap] org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

These are the files:

```
smartbox:yo du$ ls www/res/screen/android/
screen-hdpi-landscape.png   screen-ldpi-portrait.png    screen-xhdpi-landscape.png
screen-hdpi-portrait.png    screen-mdpi-landscape.png   screen-xhdpi-portrait.png
screen-ldpi-landscape.png   screen-mdpi-portrait.png
smartbox:yo du$ ls www/res/screen/ios/
screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png        screen-iphone-landscape.png
screen-ipad-landscape.png       screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png
screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png     screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png
screen-ipad-portrait.png        screen-iphone-portrait.png
screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png
```

Any hints/ideas? I'm using phonegap 3.3.0-0.18.0
What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the moment the files in www/res and gap:splash are only used for phonegap build builds, not for local builds.

To customise splashscreens for local builds, you have to do it in platforms folder.
see http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens at the bottom of the page.

Comment: In the documentation I see:
"When working in the CLI, splash screen source files are located within the project's www/res/screens subdirectory."

This is my case, right? I'm using:  
phonegap local run android

Comment: they say that but they also say in the "Splash Screens for the Android Platform" they say "If you want to use the default splash screen images provided in Cordova, you'll need to copy the png files from platforms/android/www/res/screen/android to platforms/android/res/drawable*/" Actually even for the icons I've never seen the files copied from www/res to platforms/android/res by the cli.